# How to generalize a country border using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, generalization

What are the steps for smoothening a country border using QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

From the spare information you provide I suggest to use "smooth" algorithm from processing toolbox and play a little with the settings to find the ones which deliver a suitable result for you.

[image]